# How to use closest() in jQuery for specific div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'd like to remove the closest error-class. If I select `a_1` it should remove the span after it. Same for `a_2`. But in div `.b` it should remove the error-class no matter which input I select. How can I achive this?

```
// doesn't work
form.each(function() {
    $(this).closest('.error').remove();
});
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <input class="a_1" type="text"> <!-- if I'm here, remove next -->
  <span class="error">Error</span>
  <input class="a_2" type="text"> <!-- if I'm here, remove next -->
  <span class="error">Error</span>
</div>

<div class="b">
  <input class="b_1" type="text">
  <input class="b_2" type="text">
  <input class="b_3" type="text">
  <input class="b_4" type="text">
  <input class="b_5" type="text">
  <span class="error">Error</span> <!-- remove this -->
</div>
```

Comment: "_no matter which input I select_" how are you selecting the input here?

Comment: @palaѕн I store the inputs in `form`if there are not filled out correctly. Then I loop through `form`. b_1 to b_5 are in my code radio buttons. But in this case this doesn't matter because you can select them by class. So you can do something like `$('.b_1').closest('.error').remove();` and it should remove the error-class, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`.nextAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) method instead to get the next sibling elements with class `error` and then use `:first` selector to get the first element only, so that we can only remove it where there is an actual error.

**Demo:**

```js
var $form = $(':input');
$form.each(function(){
  $(this).nextAll('.error:first').remove();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a">
  <input class="a_1" type="text"> <!-- if I'm here, remove next -->
  <span class="error">Error</span>
  <input class="a_2" type="text"> <!-- if I'm here, remove next -->
  <span class="error">Error</span>
</div>

<div class="b">
  <input class="b_1" type="text">
  <input class="b_2" type="text">
  <input class="b_3" type="text">
  <input class="b_4" type="text">
  <input class="b_5" type="text">
  <span class="error">Error</span> <!-- remove this -->
</div>
```

To validate inputs are empty or not and to see if the code is really working:

**Demo:**

```js
var $form = $(':input');
$form.each(function() {
  // if the input is not empty, hide error 
  if ($(this).val().trim() !== '') {
    $(this).nextAll('.error:first').remove();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a">
  <input class="a_1" type="text"> <!-- if I'm here, remove next -->
  <span class="error">Error</span>
  <input class="a_2" type="text" value="some text here"> <!-- if I'm here, remove next -->
  <span class="error">Error</span>
</div>

<div class="b">
  <input class="b_1" type="text">
  <input class="b_2" type="text">
  <input class="b_3" type="text">
  <input class="b_4" type="text">
  <input class="b_5" type="text">
  <span class="error">Error</span> <!-- remove this -->
</div>
```

Comment: `nextAll` worked like a charm. But why doesn't `closest()` work? Do you have an idea? Sorry for my late answer.

Comment: That because `closest()` is used to find the closest parent to the current element and `error` is not the parent of any input, it a sibling of the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

```
var $form = $(':input');
$form.each(function(){
  $(this).nextAll('.error:first').remove();
})
```

you can visit for this link . Hope this will help :)
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_closest.asp